# warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity, unity2d

Cuando compilo el código me sale este aviso:

> Assets\Scripts\Enemy1Controller.cs(116,63): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement

Creo que el error está en esa función, por el *raycast*, que se que a veces da ese error, pero he probado varias cosa y no se como solucionarlo.

```
public void Hit()
{
    //Ataque del enemigo

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position , target.transform.position - transform.position , 50.0f);

    if (hit)
    {
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.transform != null);
        {
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Player")
            {
                target.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("hitted" , true);
                target.GetComponent<PlayerController>().life = target.GetComponent<PlayerController>().life - 10;
                target.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * Knockback , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario podría terminar cerrada.

Comment: Ese error se marca en una linea.. en que linea lo marca?

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu error se encuentra en la línea 9:

```
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.transform != null);
```

justo después del último paréntesis, **tienes un punto y coma que no debería de estar ahí** y que está generando una declaración condicional vacía...

Un saludo :)